# Rearranging Mathematical Formulas for Weighted Means

Tags: probability

In a previous question [Different Ways to Calculate the Weighted Average?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4701209/different-ways-to-calculate-the-weighted-average), I tried to derive the formula myself for the Variance of Pooled Means when there are two groups:

\begin{equation}
\mu_{weighted} = \frac{\bar{x}n + \bar{y}m}{n+m} 
\end{equation}

$$Var(\mu_{weighted}) = \frac{n^2}{(n+m)^2}s_1^2 + \frac{m^2}{(n+m)^2}s_2^2 + \frac{n}{(n+m)^2} \cdot \frac{m}{(n+m)^2} (\bar{x} - \bar{y})^2$$

Where:

- the sample means are $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$.
- the sample sizes are population $n$ and $m$
- the sample variances are $Var (\bar{x}) = S_1^2$ and $Var (\bar{y}) = S_2^2$.
- you are NOT given the individual observations: $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n , y_1, y_2, \dots, y_m$

Using some algebraic manipulation, I tried to extend these formulas for "N" number of groups:

$$\mu_{\text{weighted}} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N \bar{x}_i N_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N N_i}$$

$$\text{var}(\mu_\text{weighted}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{N_i^2 s_i^2}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^n N_j\right)^2} + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i+1}^n \frac{N_i}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^n N_j\right)^2} \frac{N_j}{\left(\sum_{j=1}^n N_j\right)^2} (x̄_i - x̄_j)^2$$

**My Question:** On Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance#Sample-based_statistics), I found a similar formula (https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/0224c1c53591c619794682f2bc3560dc86530e2b) that I think can be adapted to represent a similar concept:

$$\mu_x = \frac{1}{\sum_i N_{x_i}} \left(\sum_i N_{x_i} \mu_{x_i}\right)$$

$$\sigma_x = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\sum_i N_{x_i}} - 1\right) \sum_i \left[(N_{x_i} - 1)\sigma^2_{x_i} + N_{x_i}\mu^2_{x_i}\right] - \left[\sum_i N_{x_i}\right]\mu^2_x}$$

$$ \sigma_{\bar{x}} = \frac{\sigma_x}{\sum_i N_{x_i}} = \frac{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\sum_i N_{x_i}} - 1\right) \sum_i \left[(N_{x_i} - 1)\sigma^2_{x_i} + N_{x_i}\mu^2_{x_i}\right] - \left[\sum_i N_{x_i}\right]\mu^2_x}}{\sum_i N_{x_i}}$$

**I am now trying to determine if I have done things correctly and if $\sigma_{\bar{x}} = \sqrt{\text{var}(\mu_\text{weighted})}$ - but I am not sure how to begin manipulating both equations to see if in fact $\sigma_{\bar{x}} = \sqrt{\text{var}(\mu_\text{weighted})}$ .
Can someone please show me how to do this?**

Thanks!

**Notes:**

- In the final calculation for $\sigma_{\bar{x}}$ , is the denominator ${\sum_{i=1}^N N_i} = N$ (i.e. total number of groups)?
- Or is ${\sum_{i=1}^N N_i} = n_1+ n_2 + ... n_n $ (i.e. the sum of the number of samples in all groups)?